# Loading multiple templates

Tags: go

In my code, I've a `layout`, a `view` and a `partial` templates.
I was able to load both the layout and view smoothly, now I'm addiing a new `div` in a template called `model` that is required to pop up once I clicked the button on the layout.

My code is:

```golang
import (
    "embed"
)

//go:embed libs/scripts layouts views partials scripts styles
var Views embed.FS

func Run(port string) {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.FS(Views))))

    http.HandleFunc("/messages/", messages)

    http.ListenAndServe(port, nil)
}

func main() {
    go func() {
        Run(":1235")
        println("server closed")
    }()
```

Loading the template as:

```golang
func messages(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    if tmpl, err := template.ParseFS(Views,
        "layouts/base.html",
        "views/messages.html",
        "partials/model.html"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in file parsing:", err)
    } else {
        err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "messages.html", nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error executing the template:", err)
        }
    }
}
```

The templates themselves are:
`partials/model.html`:

```html
{{define "model"}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:1235/static/styles/model.css">
<div id="modal1" class="overlay">
    <a class="cancel" href="#"></a>
    <div class="modal">
        <h2>This is Modal Overlay 1</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Click outside the modal to close.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{end}}
```

`views/messages.html`:

```html
<!-- messages -->
{{template "base" .}}
{{define "body"}}

<body>

<div></div>

<script src="http://localhost:1235/static/scripts/messages.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

`layouts/base.html`:

```html
<!-- base layout -->
{{define "base"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar-AR">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>WhatsApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:1235/static/styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" onClick="showModel()">
   Send
</button>
        {{template "body" .}}
</body>
<script>
  function showModel(){
    {{template "model" .}}
  }
</script>
</html>
{{end}}
```

Once I run the code, I got the error:

```bash
error executing the template: html/template:base.html:20:15: no such template "model"
error executing the template: html/template:base.html:20:15: no such template "model"
```

I'm getting th eerror at this code block:

```golang
<script>
  function showModel(){
    {{template "model" .}}
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. without problem. Check the paths of files.
Also you should move `Run()` from within goroutine func.